# Figure out 16*x[n-1] of a sequential BBP formula

Tags: c, gmp, pi

So, I happened to find [a slightly different version](http://en.literateprograms.org/Pi_with_the_BBP_formula_%28Python%29#Sequential_generation) of the BBP algorithm (for calculating pi):

[image]

Is there any way, perhaps by using the original BBP algorithm, to get that 16*x[n-1] term for an arbitrary value of n? Thanks.

EDIT: I meant without actually summing up {16x[0] + {16x[ 1] ... to 16x[n]}}. Is there a faster way?

Comment: Not that I can see. You might get better answers by asking on the mathematics discussion rather here, but I doubt it.

Comment: Okay. If it makes it easier, I can get the value of pi at that index: which is the integer component of 16*x[n].

Comment: In fact, I can even get multiple digits of pi in the vicinity.

Comment: I think I have a solution. I'll post it up soon if it works.